# Creating a special product function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

I am having trouble working with lists inside functions with Mathematica. Basically, I have a list of numbers and a special way to multiply them. I want to have a function that is able to create a product using the input variable list, which can vary in length. Basically, what I want is something like this:

```
prod[x__] := Product[x[[i]], {i, 1, Length[x]}]
```

However, when I try

```
prod[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I get this:

```
prod[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

> During evaluation of In[73]:= Length::argx: Length called with 4 arguments; 1 argument is expected.
>   During evaluation of In[73]:= Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.
>   During evaluation of In[73]:= Part::partd: Part specification 2[[3,4,5,1]] is longer than depth of object.
>
> `Product[2[[3, 4, 5, i]], {i, 1, Length[2, 3, 4, 5]}]`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated. I'm sure it is something simple, but I have looked and been unable to find an answer online.

Comment: The `x` above is actually a sequence of four things, not a single list with four elements. Contrast with: `In[57]:= prod[x_] := Product[x[[i]], {i, 1, Length[x]}]

In[58]:= prod[{2, 3, 4, 5}]

Out[58]= 120`

Comment: Are you aware that the built-in function `Times` will do what you appear to want? `Times[2, 3, 4, 5]` will return 120.

Comment: Or if you actually have a `List`: `Times @@ {2, 3, 4, 5}`

Comment: @m_goldberg Yes, I know that the default method exists. I only made the example with multiplication because the example I have is similar but more complex, using normally ordered products of series instead of standard multiplication :)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks, I'll try is and see what happens.